# Within transformation vs. first differencing in the over-identified case

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, generalized-moments

I have the following fixed effects model:

$S_{it}=D_{it}'\gamma + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}$

My textbook says i can use first-differencing and derive a moment  function that overidentifies $\gamma$ for $T>2$. With this I am then able to derive the asymptotic distributon of the 2-step optimal GMM estimator. So far so good.

It also says, that if I repeat this using within-transformation instead of first differencing, the asymptotic distribution of the 2-step optimal GMM might not exist (this is a question) for $T>2$, but it can work for $T=2$.

Why is that?

I understamd that for $T=2$, the first-difference and within transformations will produce the same results, and with larger $T$, the first-difference estimator will become less efficient. But how does this relate to the 2-step optimal GMM and why would using within-transformation in the over-identified case result in the asymptotic distribution not existing?